# How to do language Specific sort in C#?

Tags: c#, sorting, cultureinfo

I have a generic list which can contain values in different languages based on current user's language preference. For example if user has selected Japanese, i will populate Japanese text in to the list.

I want to sort it based on Japanese text, not phonetic sort. We have a sort method with list or we can use a little extension method, that is fine. All I want to know is how do i sort based on different language?

I checked out some documentation on MSDN about invariant culture etc. which did not help.

Comment: Just a thought: you could override the `Sort()` method of your list and implement the exact sort way to want depending on the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a7zyyk0c.aspx

Basically, you want to do the following:

```
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("ja-JP");
```

After that you use the normal "sort" methods (as defined in Array, `List<T>`, etc.) and they will obey the Japanese rules for string sorting.

Comment: Don't do this, changing a thread's culture can have wide ranging side-effects.  Use StringComparer.Culture or a string.Compare() overload that takes CultureInfo.

Comment: @Hans: if the user has selected Japanese as their language of choice woudln't it make sense to display things appropriately for that culture?

Comment: If they did that, there wouldn't be a need to do anything special.  The default sort order is already based on the operating system language.

Comment: @Hans: I'm a bit confused, the original post said, "I have a list which contains values based on the current user's language preference"..."if the user has selected Japanses, I will populated Japanese text into the list"  I assumed (perhaps incorrectly) that this means the user has selected some option somewhere in the program that sets the language preference, this is often useful in a setting where there's multiple users on a computer (one, for instance, where Japanese is not the OS. language)...am I still missing your point?